# Subplots of multidimensional arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a 10x10x10 array, `z`. How do I plot everything in the SAME window so that I would have the 3 plots for `z(:,:,1)` and below it the three plots for `z(:,:,2)` etc.?

This is what I have so far:

```
for i = 1:10

z=z(:,:,i);  
figure(i)  
subplot(1,2,1) 
surf(z)

%code, obtain new array called  "new1"...

subplot(1,2,2)  
surf(new1)

%code, obtain new array called "new2"...

subplot(1,3,3)  
surf(new2)

end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the first two subplots are supposed to be `subplot(1,3,1)` and `subplot(1,3,2)`. Also, try inserting `hold on` after each `subplot` command --- this should allow you to keep whatever has been plotted before.

```
for i = 1:10

z=z(:,:,i);  
figure(i)  
subplot(1,3,1)
hold on;
surf(z)

%code, obtain new array called  "new1"...

subplot(1,3,2) 
hold on; 
surf(new1)

%code, obtain new array called "new2"...

subplot(1,3,3) 
hold on; 
surf(new2)

end;
```

Comment: I don't think the hold is necessary in this case - drawing in a different subplot won't override the previous ones. But it would if more than one surface was plotted in each subplot. Still, +1 for catching the bug.

Answer (score 1):

What is `new1` and `new2`? Are they the same for all rows? Or also 3D arrays?

I think you need something like this:

```
for i = 1:10
    subplot(10*3,3,(i-1)*3+1)
    surf(z(:,:,i))
    subplot(10*3,3,(i-1)*3+2)
    surf(new1)
    subplot(10*3,3,(i-1)*3+3)
    surf(new2)

end
```

Or more generally for variable size of z:

```
N = size(z,3);
for i = 1:N
    subplot(N*3,3,(i-1)*3+1)
    surf(z(:,:,i))
    subplot(N*3,3,(i-1)*3+2)
    surf(new1)
    subplot(N*3,3,(i-1)*3+3)
    surf(new2)

end
```